# text indentation to multi level array?

Tags: php

i'm trying without success to build a parser which should convert text indentation (TAB KEY) to a multi-level php array (i'm very new to programming)

i have a txt file written using this format:

```
test1
    test2
        blah3
    blah4
    blah5
        more content
some more
    and more content
```

after parsing it should return an array like:

```
$myarray[0]['c']                   = "test1";
$myarray[0]['s'][0]['c']           = "test2";
$myarray[0]['s'][0]['s'][0]['c']   = "blah3";
$myarray[0]['s'][1]['c']           = "blah4";
$myarray[0]['s'][2]['c']           = "blah5";
$myarray[0]['s'][2]['s'][0]['c']   = "more content";
$myarray[1]['c']                   = "some more";
$myarray[1]['s'][0]['c']           = "and more content";
```

is possible to build such function in php?

before you ask i can't use xml because i already have that txt file
that would have to be converted first to xml

very thank you in advance for your answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you can write such a parser. What you are trying to do is actually to build a tree data structure that is stored as an array of arrays in which the leaf nodes are the text values and the branches are determined by TABs.

What you need to do is:

- read the input text file line by line
- use a variable to keep the current indentation
- for each line, determine the number of leading tabs (indentation)
- if the indentation matches the previous line's indentation you add the rest of the text on that line as a sibling to the current array
- if it's 1-greater than current indentation, add a branch (another sub-array)
- it it's less than the current indentation, set current array correspondingly

Pease let me know if you need more clarification on any of these steps.

**UPDATE**

Here are a few pointers.

You can read the file line by line with something like this:

```
$file_handle = fopen("myfile", "r");
while (!feof($file_handle)) {
   $line = fgets($file_handle);

   // process line here

}
fclose($file_handle);
```

You can detect the number of leading TABs in each line using code like this:

```
$numTabs = 0;
while(substr($line, $numTabs, 1) == "\t")
{
    $numTabs++;
}
```

Then obtain the rest of the line using another call to [substr](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php):

```
$lineValue = substr($line, $numTabs);
```

To test if a line is blank you may use [trim](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php):

```
if(trim($line) == ""){
   // line is blank.. just skip it!
}
```

Comment: well... this is obvious! but thanks for your answer :) i have problems with substrings and in detecting indentation errors such as two or more tabs instead of one, empty lines and so on

Comment: then you really have a number of different questions. to get the best of this site you will have to ask them separately but I will try to update the answer with some specifics..

Comment: hi, thanks for your help! i have more problems sadly. i've used a reference $this->currentArray = &$this->tree[...][...]; to store the current position but i don't think it is a good idea since i can go deeper (ie $this->currentArray[...]) but i can't go upper ie parent_array($this->currentArray)

Comment: @sveva - please ask a different question. the format of SO is one question/post.